# Como usar un spinner dentro de un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Actualmente tengo un `RecyclerView` en el que quiero añadir una especie de `Spinner`. Quiero que mi `Spinner` me muestre una serie de datos pero, solo quiero verlos, no quiero que me deje seleccionar ninguno. ¿Como puedo desactivarlos todos para que solo me enseñe la lista? He probado varios ejemplos y tutoriales y no hay manera, creo que el problema viene de estar usando un `RecyclerView`. Tambien necesito que aparezca un texto por defecto en el `Spinner`, por ejemplo: lista de items.
Adjunto el código de mi `adapter`, aqui es donde trato todo del `Spinner`

```
    public class ProductDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductDetailAdapter.ProductHolder> {
    private List<Purchases> items;
    Context context;
    public ProductDetailAdapter(List<Purchases> items, Context context, String lastActivity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lastActivity = lastActivity;
        this.items = items;
    }


    @Override
    public ProductDetailAdapter.ProductHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardpurchasedetail, parent, false);
        return new ProductHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductHolder holder, int position) {
        int spinnerPos = 0;
       // ArrayAdapter adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item , items.get(position).getItemsnames());
       ArrayAdapter adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item , items.get(position).getItemsnames()){
           @Override
           public boolean isEnabled(int position){
             return false;
           }

           @Override
           public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                       ViewGroup parent) {
               View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
               TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                   tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
               return view;
           }
       };
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        holder.spinner.setAdapter(
                new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        adapter,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                        this.context));
   }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    public class ProductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Spinner spinner;

        public ProductHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            spinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner) ;

        }


    }

}
```

[NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one) , de esta forma he podido mostrar un texto en el titulo pero, en cuando puslo el spinner me desaparece.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Ya he conseguido que funcione!
El problema era que me estaba mostrando el texto del `spinner` en blanco y el fondo era blanco también, conclusión: no veía nada. Ahora que ya los veo se que me funciona la función para ver que elemento esta seleccionado y por tanto puedo hacer que no me cambie el valor del `spinner` nunca. 
Por tanto, lo que tenia funcionaba, únicamente tenia que cambiar el `xml` que hacia referencia a los `items` del `Spinner`.

Muchas gracias! :D

Answer (score -1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno este tutorial te podría servir, estoy seguro.

[pop-up recyclerview](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)